# Fixing an image to a fullscreen div

Tags: html, image, fullscreen

my question is simple.
I have this page: http://vacanor.com/tests/lared

There is that image in the middle of the first section that floats on the screen. I want to stick that image in the first section preservating its position whenever I change the screen size. I've tryed everything but I can't.

Here is a video about what is bothering me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U37_1cY8nAs

My html(including second section):

```
<div class="container-a">
    <!--<div class="col-lg-12">-->
        <div class="img-cover">
            <center><img class="img-cover-i floating" src="img/logo-background.png" alt="Logo">
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--</div>-->
<!-- Presentación -->
<div class="container-b">
   <!-- <div class="col-lg-12">-->
        <div class="ani">
            <div class="intro">
                <h1 class="animated fadeInDown animated-d-1 cd-headline slide">
                    Bienvenido a La Red
                <small>
                    <span class="text-primary cd-words-wrapper"       style="width: 207px;">
                        <b class="is-hidden">Construir </b>
                        <b class="is-hidden">Jugar</b>
                        <b class="is-hidden">Sobrevivir</b>
                        <b class="is-visible">Divertir-se </b>
                    </span>
                    <span>nunca será lo mismo.</span>
                </small>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my css:

```
.img-cover {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 95%;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
margin-top: 50px;
}
.img-cover-i {
position: relative;
}
.container-a {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index: -2;
background-image: url('../img/cover-background.jpg');
background-position: center;
background-repeat: none;
background-size: cover;
}
.container-b {
margin: 0 auto;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -3;
top:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not really understand your question, so here are 3 fixes to how I understood it.

```
.container-a {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index: -2;
background-image: url('../img/cover-background.jpg');
background-position: center;
background-repeat: none;
background-size: cover;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

The above code should make your image not get out of the div when resizing the screen, and below is an example of how to resize the image accordingly;

```
.img-cover-i {
position: relative;
height:calc(100% - 50px)
}
```

Also, if you want your Logo to follow the screen but not be visible outside the container a, use this code:

```
.img-cover-i {
margin-left:calc(50% - 237px);
position: fixed;
}
.container-a {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index: -2;
background-image: url('../img/cover-background.jpg');
background-position: center;
background-repeat: none;
background-size: cover;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Also, if using this code, remove the  that wraps the img in the html part.
I hope this helped.